# Pandas - sum up each member of a pair in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
eventScore
5-4 
6-2 6-0
6-2 6-3
7-6 6-2
2-6 4-6
1-6 1-3
```

The left of each pair is the player score, the right of each pair is the opponentScore.

So for each column, I need to add the left of the dash and the right of the dash.

Final output:

```
eventScore     playerScore   opponentScore
5-4            5             4
6-2 6-0        12            2  
6-2 6-3        12            5
7-6 6-2        13            8
2-6 4-6        6             12
1-6 1-3        2             9
```

Data can be reformatted as necessary.

Edit: Original question had unnecessary strings in the score, made it easier to read.

Comment: What is `RET` in your dataframes?

Comment: They're tennis matches that ended early, but you can assume the RET is removed if it makes solving the problem easier (since removing it is trivial)

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem individually. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you finished before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: In particular, you'll have to convert the string to a pair of integers.  I recommend using `split` and `int` methods.  From there, you should be able to construct a coding attempt.

Comment: I tried using split, but it's difficult since it's not necessarily one pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not particularly elegant, but this works, using regex to find digits before and after `-`:

```
df['playerScore'] = df.eventScore.str.findall('(\d+)-').apply(pd.Series, dtype=float).sum(1)
df['opponentScore'] = df.eventScore.str.findall('-(\d+)').apply(pd.Series, dtype=float).sum(1)

>>> df
  eventScore  playerScore  opponentScore
0        5-4          5.0            4.0
1    6-2 6-0         12.0            2.0
2    6-2 6-3         12.0            5.0
3    7-6 6-2         13.0            8.0
4    2-6 4-6          6.0           12.0
5    1-6 1-3          2.0            9.0
```

Comment: It seems like when there's only one pair, the playerScore and opponentScore switch. (In my output using this code, the playerScore and opponentScore are correct for all rows except the first one). I can flip them with a simple np.where though

Comment: np.where worked (copied the eventScore column, reversed it if the len was 3, then dropped the copied column). This works.